# Java comments regex: egrep "(/\*\* | /* | \*/ | \*\*/)" text.txt

Tags: regular-expression

I'm trying to extract lines starting or ending a Java comment:

What I have is:

> egrep "(/** | /* | */ | **/)" text.txt

I noticed that this works for all lines (such as /* comment */) except those that contain **only** /*, /**, **/ or */ and nothing preceding or following it.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern `egrep "(/** | /* | */ | **/)" text.txt` contains explicit spaces; try it without them: `egrep "(/**|/*|*/|**/)" text.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You are including spaces inside your pattern, and you are forgetting the comment lines starting with `//`.

With:

```
egrep "(/\*\*|/\*|\*/|\*\*/|//)" text.txt
```

I see all lines that start or end comments, including lines that only contain the tokens. For example...

text.txt:

```
this should not be there
// this should be there
/* and this too */
/** even this
should be there too **/
/* or
that
also */
not this
/*
*/
/**
**/
```

Output:

```
// this should be there
/* and this too */
/** even this
should be there too **/
/* or
also */
/*
*/
/**
**/
```